# XAMPP SSL Certificate Stopped Working For Localhost After Chrome Update

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, xampp

My XAMPP V3.2.2 was working fine with green https lock until this Chrome update to Version 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit)

It still works with Microsoft Edge and FireFox.
How can I get it to work in latest Chrome?
Here is the error:

> Subject Alternative Name Missing
>
> The certificate for this site does
>   not contain a Subject Alternative Name extension containing a domain
>   name or IP address.

Here is what I did to get the green lock for all browsers before:

1. "C:\xampp\apache\makecert.bat"

   Fill passowrds, hit  for everything BUT define "localhost"!!!
   Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:localhost
   (Certificates are issued for domain name zone only!)
2. Restart apache
3. Chrome -> Settings -> Search "Certificate" -> Manage Certificates -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities -> Import -> "C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\server.crt" -> Must Ask "YES" for confirmation!
4. https://localhost/testssl.php -> [OK, Green!]

**Again now it still works for all browsers except latest Chrome.**

Comment: @JoshLee Thanks but I use XAMPP specifically to generate and assign certificates. I only run C:\xampp\apache\makecert.bat and looking for an answer to solve the problem with XAMPP rather than manual self-signed certificates.

Comment: As the question is currently written you don't ask specifically for a solution involving makecert but just for a solution to make it work again. According to the question you are not even aware that the problem is that makecert does not create SAN. Insofar it is actually a duplicate of the other question. If you want to know how to fix the problem of missing SAN with makecert please ask exactly this instead. But the answer might be that it is not possible with makecert. See also [this discussion](https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=256423&sid=5118db64708ed66ea89f6b3481237986).

Comment: What to do with latest chrome. It still shows as Your connection is not private